# What's benefit of using JVM instead of compiler, which both are OS dependent

Tags: compilation, jvm

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153792/why-the-java-language-need-bytecode-why-java-design-in-this-way)
and it mentioned the concept of "Write once, run anywhere." is a major reason for JVM.
But since JVM is OS dependant, someone needs to write different JVMs for different OS. and the OS must installed corresponding JVM to make sure the java code can run.
So how is it different from writing different compilers for different OS? Say there are 2 OS, can you tell me what's the difference between writing compilers and JVM for these 2 OS. Is it just because it is more difficult to write, or there are actually more historical reasons?

Comment: Hint: most people aren't writing compilers or JVMs. They're writing applications (including web sites, web services etc).

Comment: thanks for the quick response, but probably I still need more hints ; )

Comment: Well, you're asking about the benefit of *using* a JVM. A *user* doesn't need to *implement* a JVM (or a compiler, of course). So thinking about the experience of the people who *do* write compilers and JVMs is somewhat irrelevant. It's like saying "an automatic gearbox is hard to build, so how does it help someone driving"?

Comment: Well, someone has to use the compiler. Unless you’re assuming everything is open source and every user is happy to compile the source code themself, the application developer is the one using the compiler, producing as many binaries for as many systems as he considers reasonable. Bad luck if your system is not among the list. The availability of a compiler for your system doesn’t help you if you don’t have the source code (or are an ordinary user with no idea how to use a compiler). If the program is deployed as as Java program, you *can* use it on every system with a JVM (at least in theory).

Comment: @Holger so jvm is about to help application developers to have a better experience, in the senes that they don't need to compile the program by themselves when it is shifted with .class files?

Comment: @HKIT that’s one point of view. Supporting *x* target platforms requires effort and the developer has to make a cut somewhere. Using a JVM reduces the required effort, down to the point of not scaling with *x* at all. But the other point is, as already mentioned by others, the target platform may not even exist by the time, the application is developed. But look at it from the other side. It happens all the time that an application is offered for one platform only and if that’s not the one you’re using, you’re out of luck. Unless the supported platform is the JVM.

Comment: @Holger excellent explanation, got it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you write software and you know that it will be used on XY OS or architecture, and you are happy to build your software for that target. But there could be an infinite number of different targets, and some of them might also be unknown to you. So it's not a question of what's more difficult.
You can't compile me code without me telling you where I will run it. You can on the other hand compile it to Java bytecode and let everybody run it where ever they want - as long as they have a JVM running there. Compiled Java code (even if I hate it) is already good to go on targets that don't even exist today!

Edit:

The end-code, the binary must always be target specific. Take 3 systems, a Windows PC (S1), a Linux PC (S2) and a Coretex M3 microcontroller (S3). The "traditional" way to deploy software to these platforms in case of C for example is to write the source code and compile the code using 3 different compilers, one specific to each platform. This results in 3 different binaries that are not portable. Code compiled to S1 will not run on S2. People using S3 platform can only run this program if the developers compile it specifically to S3. You can't introduce future platforms (S4) without somebody creating a compiler for that platform first. (Effort X, we come back to that)

With Java and Java-byte-code, you have an imaginary target, a virtual machine, the JVM. You only need one compiler, one that compiles for JVM. (This is not 100% true, but we can go with that for now.) There is only one compiled code, for one target only, for a JVM and nothing else at all. This has simplified one compiling aspect, but introduced another problem: JVM must exist on every platform you want to run this code. The JVM must be created in a platform specific way, one specific JVM for S1, S2 and S3. But developers don't have to worry about that, as far as we are concerned JVM just exists pretty much for every platform where it makes sense. The developer is not concerned with the diversity of the platforms anymore. Users ask: "Can I run your program on XYZ platform?", and the answer is: "Yes, as long as you can put a JVM onto it.". This also goes for platforms that non't yet exist. Obviously the a JVM must be created for this future platform first, this is similar than "Effort X" from above. Can you run Java code on a quantum computer? You bet! As soon as there will be (is) a JVM for it.

This creates a very handy situation but does not make Java better or worse than another language, this is one aspect you want to consider, certainly an interesting one.

Comment: when you say "You can't compile my code without me telling you where I will run it", does it mean those code will have platform specific logic? If the Java API specification is generic for different OS, shouldn't it be the compiler's job to turn those code into corresponding machine code matching the OS architecture?

Comment: Take C for example. You write a simple program and take the C compiler, but which one? There's one for Windows, one for Linux, one for AVR, one for Espressif, Coretex M4 etc. These compile environment specific code. In compile time you need to decide what your target is. The target of the Java compiler is a JVM. It is irrelevant where the JVM is running, may it be a PC, a microcontroller, whatever architecture or OS. So compiled Java code is portable.